# Can a smooth curve of any genus be realized on $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves

By the degree-genus formula $$g = \frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2},$$ we know the possibility of the genus $g$ of a smooth curve on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is limited by its degree $d$. What about a smooth curve on $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$? Can every genus $g\geq 0$ be realized?

Comment: The genus of a smooth curve of bidegree $(a,b)$ is $(a-1)(b-1)$.

Comment: @Sasha So the answer is positive?

Comment: And what do you think?

Comment: @Sasha By bidegree $(a,b)$ of a smooth curve $C \subset \mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$, I guess you mean the bidegree of a bihomogeneous polynomial $F$ which defines $C$. So any genus $g\geq-1$ can be realized when $a=2$ and $b=g+1$.

Comment: @Sasha, could you write up this answer or give permission for someone else to do this? There are a couple of duplicates running around of this question and it would be nice to get a good answer down somewhere and close the rest as duplicates.

Comment: @KReiser: If you think it makes sense, please go on. Actually, I don't think a permission is needed in the case of a formula that is so standard.

Comment: @YuhangChen: Right, any hyperelliptic curve can be embedded into $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @Sasha What about the curve with genus $g=-1$?

Comment: @YuhangChen: The genus of a smooth curve is nonnegative.

Comment: @Sasha So the genus formula breaks down when $a=2,b=0$?

Comment: @YuhangChen: Can you figure out what is the curve defined by an equation of bidegree $(2,0)$?

Comment: @Sasha Two copies of $\mathbb{CP}^1$?

Comment: @YuhangChen: Correct. So, it is not connected.

Comment: @Sasha So the genus is not well defined, and hence the formula no longer applies?

Comment: @YuhangChen: The formula computes the arithmetic genus, which agrees with the geometric genus for smooth connected curves, but not in general.

Comment: @Sasha Now everything makes sense. Thanks for the discussion.